# How to execute a shell built-in command

Tags: go, executable

I am trying to find out if a program exists on Linux and I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script). I tried executing this from my go program and it keeps giving me an error saying it can-not find "command" in my $PATH, which is to be expected since it's a built-in command in linux and not a binary. So my question is how to execute built in commands of linux from within go programs?

```
exec.Command("command", "-v", "foo")
```

error: exec: "command": executable file not found in $PATH

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just like that article says, "command" is a shell built-in. You can do this natively in go via [`exec.LookPath`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath).

If you must, you can either use the system `which` binary, or you can execute `command` from within a shell,

```
exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "command -v foo")
```

Comment: For bash users, `type` is preferable over `which` (the latter is a script).

Comment: Also note that bash had a serious security bug this year, although this has been fixed. But if you have a choice, prefer the default shell `sh` (usually this is Dash) for all server-side shell scripting.

Comment: This worked for me but instead of using the complete /bin/bash path I just used sh as below
exec.Command("sh", "-c", "command -v foo") otherwise I was getting the exit error 26/27 for most of my excecutions.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if it is a built in command that doesn't need parameters you could do something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("uuidgen").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", out)
}
```

This would print out a unique ID like the following : 4cdb277e-3c25-48ef-a367-ba734ce407c1 just like calling it directly from the command line.

Comment: uuidgen is not a shell built-in command. A built-in command are e.g. alias, source, read, printf etc. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins