# GO filevault status, os/exec or plist

Tags: macos, go, terminal, exec, filevault

I need to write a code in GO that checks the status of fileVault.
Since I could not find the plist file that contains that information I turned to check it via the terminal using os/exec package.

I know that from the terminal I can execute the command " fdesetup status" to get the status, so I've tried the following code:

```
    cmd := exec.Command( "fdesetup status")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
```

Which resulted in the error: *"exec: "fdesetup status": executable file not found in $PATH: "*

I've tried to change the exec command to: "*date*" instead of "*fdesetup status*" which worked fine, so it seems there is no need to add some kind of invocation to the terminal.

To get around it I've tried to use `exec.Command("echo", "fdesetup status")`

and `exec.Command("echo", "$(fdesetup status)")`   both worked in the terminal, but did not provide the information when executed via GO.

I would appreciate any help figuring out how to gain fileVault status information via GO.

Comment: Try the full path. Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229486/how-to-execute-a-shell-built-in-command/34229542#34229542